# User can create DX Unlocked package but not a version

Tags: salesforcedx, dev-hub, unlocked-package

When creating a DX Unlocked Package version from a DevHub org and user with Second Generation Packages Enabled (1h ago)

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p "myapp" -x -json
```

I get the following errors:

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  No such column 'Instance'
>   on sobject of type Package2VersionCreateRequest
>
> Try this:  Your org does not have permission to specify a build
>   instance for your package version. Verify that you are authenticated
>   to the desired org and try again. Otherwise, contact Salesforce
>   Customer Support for more information.

When I call the command without the `-json` param it takes a minute and then comes back with other metadata errors that all seem to miss a custom object which is part of the package.

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  TestQuoteCtrl: Invalid
>   type: MyQuote__c,TestMyQuoteCtrl: Invalid type:
>   MyLineItem__c,QuoteManager: Invalid type

Answer (score 3):

My solution was two-fold:

1. Don't use the `-json` parameter as it doesn't print the real root causes
2. As many documentations and blogs about this topic I forgot to specify the `-f` parameter in my version create command. If omitted the version is created from a default scratch org which in my case was incompatible with some metadata settings.

   sfdx force:package:version:create -p my-app -d force-app --wait 10 -v DevHub -x -f config/project-scratch-def.json

Comment: cool, another possibility is if you use Permission Sets and your Admin profile doesn't have all permissions specified

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a parameter as -json, but --json

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm

> sfdx force:package:version:create
> **[--json]**
> [--loglevel LOGLEVEL]
> [-v TARGETDEVHUBUSERNAME]
> [--apiversion APIVERSION]
> [-p PACKAGE]
> [-d PATH]
> [-f DEFINITIONFILE]
> [-b BRANCH]
> [-t TAG]
> [-k INSTALLATIONKEY]
> [-x]
> [-w WAIT]
> [-a VERSIONNAME]
> [-n VERSIONNUMBER]
> [-e VERSIONDESCRIPTION]
> [-c]
> [--releasenotesurl RELEASENOTESURL]
> [--postinstallurl POSTINSTALLURL]
> [--postinstallscript POSTINSTALLSCRIPT]
> [--uninstallscript UNINSTALLSCRIPT]
> [--skipvalidation]